# Getting level of Symfony/Doctrine entity in hierarchical structure with Gedmo extension

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sylius

I have a table (`ayrshireminis_car_category`) which is built with a hierarchical structure.

I am attempting to use the [Doctrine Gedmo extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) to pull out a "level" member variable which I am using elsewhere, so i'm expecting a parent to have a level of 1, a child to have a level of 2 a grandchild to have a level of 3 and so on...

This is my mapped entity:

```
AyrshireMinis\CarBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    table: ayrshireminis_car_category
    gedmo:
        tree:
            type: nested
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            length: 11
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 150
        active:
            type: boolean
            default: true
        position:
            type: integer
            length: 11
        level:
            type: integer
            gedmo:
                - treeLevel
        createdAt:
              type: datetime
              gedmo:
                  timestampable:
                      on: create
              column: created_at
        updatedAt:
            type: datetime
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: update
            column: updated_at
    manyToOne:
        parent:
            targetEntity: AyrshireMinis\CarBundle\Entity\Category
            inversedBy: children
            gedmo:
                - treeParent
        createdBy:
            targetEntity: \Sylius\Component\Core\Model\UserInterface
            joinColumn:
                nullable: false
                name: created_by
            gedmo:
                blameable:
                    on: create
        updatedBy:
            targetEntity: \Sylius\Component\Core\Model\UserInterface
            joinColumn:
                nullable: false
                name: updated_by
            gedmo:
                blameable:
                    on: update
    oneToMany:
        products:
            targetEntity: AyrshireMinis\CarBundle\Entity\Product
            mappedBy: category
```

With this mapping I get the following error:

> Missing properties: left, right in class -
>   AyrshireMinis\CarBundle\Entity\Category 500 Internal Server Error -
>   InvalidMappingException

However, I do not want a "left" and "right" column in my table. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing the schema and relying heavily on the Gedmo extension I was able to extract the "level" like this:

```
/**
 * get a numeric representation of the press category level
 * i.e. parent categories - 0, child categories - 1, grandchild categories - 2 etc...
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getLevel()
{
    $level = 0;

    $category = $this;

    // parent category
    if ($category->hasParent() === false) {
        return $level;
    }

    while ($category = $category->getParent()) {
        $level++;
    }

    return $level;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasParent()
{
    return ($this->parent != null ? true : false);
}
```